# GE 230/208 zoneline AC/heater unit

Tags: wiring

I have a GE zoneline AC/heater unit 230/208.  going on a double pole 30 amp breaker. is 10-3 to small should go 8-3[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the top right hand part of the label in your picture it shows that there are three different heat strips that go into this unit. The largest requires a 30A breaker for protection, but to be able to answer your question you need to contact the seller and see if they have the information on which heat strip is actually installed, or you can contact GE Appliances and see if the serial or model number can tell you what size the heat strip is.

Comment: Yes as retired says, we need to know which heat strip it comes with.  Our locality requires that we circle with magic marker the strip installed. We also need to know the length of the branch circuit and any other factors that could effect voltage drop.

Comment: It's only going to be about 10 of wire if that. I will check on the heat strip and get back with y'all thanks

Comment: Sorry 10ft of wire

Comment: It is a 30amp unit is what GE told me

Comment: Your maximum current according to your picture is about 21.2 amps so using a 3% drop calculation you should be good for about 150' using a #10 conductor.